# Why is my C# Windows Forms App generating this code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Why is this code being generated when I create a "c# Windows Forms Application"?

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

The reason I ask is because I've never seen this before. I am used to creating projects and them being empty, just like this.

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {

    }
}
```

Ive never seen that "STAThread" or "Application.etc..." stuff before.

I just upgraded to Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: ...because that is a starter template that also includes a bare bones definition for `Form1` and you could compile and run and you would see a blank form show up?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are WinForms applications STAThread by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659220/why-are-winforms-applications-stathread-by-default)

Comment: You sure you haven't created console applications? Because that code has always been there for winforms applications. I think the comments were added at some point but the rest has been there for as long as I can remember.

Comment: @RaymondChen I think this is about all the stuff that is there and not just `STAThread`, so I don't think that is the best choice for this being a duplicate of.

Comment: The template would have been quite useless if it only generated a blank entry point without the code that actually starts the application and displays the main form. If you want a truly blank app, then don't use templates.

Comment: It is not generated, both snippets come from the project templates.  Respectively for a Winforms and a Console app.  There isn't much they could do to precook console app code, the Winforms code is sufficiently obtuse that new programmers would have a hard time getting that right from scratch.  It is all important and all very well documented.  Picking up an introductory book about Winforms programming is a good idea since guessing at it rarely turns out well.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. It was a bit of blunder on my behalf. I just got confused between the Form1.cs file and Program.cs file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably all the solution/project you do with your old Visual studio version were Console/CommandLine projects. What you create with Visual Studio is a WindowsForm project (when you create the project it open by default a template with an empty form) that is different because it use a "graphic" environment instead of the black and white console you are familiar with.

To be specific what the code do is:

```
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
```

Enables visual styles for the application. Visual styles are the colors, fonts, and other visual elements that form an operating system theme. ([MSDN LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.enablevisualstyles?view=netframework-4.8)).

```
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
```

Is a property that handle some compatibility with old frameworks. If your application is not updated from a .NET Framework 1.0 or .NET Framework 1.1 application leave it to the default value 'false'. If you not know what i'm saying.... leave it to the default value 'false' :D

```
    Application.Run(new Form1());
```

When your application start it launch the form called 'Form1' (you can see it in your solution explorer).

for the STAThread explanation i remand you to [the link in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659220/why-are-winforms-applications-stathread-by-default) from @Raymond Chen, but i think is a bit too hard for you, just think that is a "must" for windowsForm application for now :)

Comment: Thank you for further explaining what that code does. I was used to seeing the more empty "Form1.cs" file which explains why I was confused to see the extra code that is inside of the "Program.cs" file.

Answer (score 0):

That is auto-code what visual studio generate to run in Program.cs in any winform project
And this is code Program.cs:

```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;
   using System.Windows.Forms;

   namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
   {
   static class Program
   {
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
    }
    }
```