# Using Drag-and-Drop while using MTAThread

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop

Today I came across a peculiar problem, DragDrop functions do NOT work while using MTAThread. I have searched the MSDN and I have googled various combinations of the key words.

Can anyone please explain to me why this isn't allowed? Is there a way to get around it?

Comment: Can you explain why you're using an `MTAThread`? Many Windows Forms controls that wrap their COM equivalents require `STAThread`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102437/why-do-all-winforms-programs-require-the-stathread-attribute

Comment: STA required.  Never a real problem, you're dragging between UI objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would get the following error, which might explain the reason a bit:

```
System.Threading.ThreadStateException: Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made. Ensure that your Main function has STAThreadAttribute marked on it.
```

Generally, use STAThread on any thread that creates UI inorder to prevent unresponsive / hanging UI. Nothing prevents you from creating a separate thread ( but STA ) for a window so that your UI is responsive:

```
 Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
  {
     Window1 w = new Window1();
     w.Show();

     System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
  });



  thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
  thread.Start();
```

There can be worker threads which can be MTA. The worker thread(s) can interact with the UI thread by passing messages to the Dispatcher ( in case of WPF)

Have a look at this blog post, old, but provides lots of information on Apartments and Pumping

[Apartments and Pumping in the CLR](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cbrumme/archive/2004/02/02/66219.aspx)