# VB.NET Threading with Join() method without freezing form

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

Hello I am studying multithreading with join method

I am trying to create multiple threads and run thread in order.

I know that join method is able to join threads and run threads in order.

However, form is updating text box, but whole form is freezing so i can't click any button in the form

Here is code that I have..

> ```
> Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
>     Dim T_List As New ArrayList
>     Dim VALE As Integer = 99
>     For i = 0 To 2
>         VALE = i
>         t = New Thread(New ThreadStart(Sub() run_t(VALE, 10 + (5 * VALE))))
>         t.IsBackground = True
>         t.Start()
>         t.Join()
>         ' T_List.Add(t)
>     Next
>
> End Sub
>
>
> Private Sub run_t(t_num As Integer, number As Integer)
>     For i = 0 To number
>         Thread.Sleep(100)
>         CounterBox.AppendText("thread : " & t_num & " : " & i.ToString() + vbNewLine)
>         If i Mod 2 = 0 Then
>             ComboBox1.Items.Add(i)
>         End If
>
>     Next
> End Sub
> ```

I was checking "STATHREAD"
[STATHREAD and main thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16950316/stathread-and-main-thread)
and
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182351.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

however, STATHREAD seems not working for this case.

what can be the solution to use Join method for threads without freezing form..

Answer (score 0):

In VB.Net Form, I would recommand you to use `BackgroundWorker` which will let you to:

- launch a calculation thread
- interact with your Form without blocking the UI thread.

[BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx)

`Thread.Join` is a blocking method which should never be used in GUI event handlers.

Comment: `BackgroundWorker` is a legacy technology superseded by Task Parallel Library (i.e. `Task.Run`) and `async`/`await`.

Comment: I totally agree, but I don't know which .NET Framework he's using.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    Dim tt As New Thread(AddressOf working) : tt.Start()
End Sub

Sub working()
    Dim T_List As New ArrayList
    Dim VALE As Integer = 99
    For i = 0 To 2
        VALE = i
        run_t(VALE, 10 + (5 * VALE))
        
' T_List.Add(t)
    Next
End Sub

Sub run_t(t_num As Integer, number As Integer)
    For i = 0 To number
        Thread.Sleep(100)
        CounterBox.AppendText("thread : " & t_num & " : " & i.ToString() + vbNewLine)
        If i Mod 2 = 0 Then
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(i)
        End If
        
    Next
End Sub
```